# Vedas/Purana in Sanskrit language

Tags: puranas, culture, brahmins

Do we still have Gurukula in INDIA/Bharat. which is having new generation subjects with our traditional Vedas/Purana in Sanskrit language.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are in fact quite a few Vedic Gurukulams /Vedic Pathsalas in India right now.

[Here](http://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_veda/vedapathashala.html) you can find a comprehensive list of those.